# find the source for jquery contains pseudo-selector

Tags: jquery

I would like to find the portion of the [jquery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) that implements the [contains psuedo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). Because I'd like to see how they've done it to give me ideas for something similar I'm working on.

But I can't seem to find where this is implemented.

Can anyone else?

Comment: a simple browser search using CTRL+F could do this

Comment: line# 3941 in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js enjoy.. based on sizzle css selector engine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It belongs to Sizzle (selectors engine): https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L753

Comment: Interestingly enough, it is anti-mentioned in the CSS3 spec at : http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#content-selectors  .  John R and jquery's original goals was to implement a js framework that fully supported the complete CSS selector spec, which they moved to Sizzle once it was fully-realized. Now it has features like `:contains` that are no longer in the spec.

Comment: @Anthony: I'm sure they cannot just remove it according the specs due to bc

Comment: I'm sure they don't want to.  I think they go out of there way to piggy back on the browser's selector engine to avoid redundancy and keep performance high, but why throw out a neat (and working) feature just because the w3c committee thought it wasn't quite ready?  Frankly, I wish jquery and the CSS think tank would get a true parent/previous selector out the door as their excuses (w3c's,not jquery's) are wearing thin.  If it's too "dangerous", then limit the generation climb.